# Is it possible to just replace a particular line in a file without rewriting the whole file

Tags: database, go, io

I was trying to construct a function which would say given a line number replace that line with another string. Currently, I'm achieving this by reading the whole file into my RAM, modifying the line in RAM and rewriting the whole file back. I was wondering how databases managed to achieve this since this is a rather frequent operation over there.

Comment: May be index the line numbers to file positions (offsets). Then if you want to modify a line then see its position in file and seek the file over there. Replace the line using write or writeat taking care that it does not overwrite the next line data. Otherwise you will have to adjust & write the subsequent sections and re index those parts. Can divide a single file into smaller segments to minimize the modification work

Comment: You don't need to read the whole file into memory (so-called "slurping"). You can roll like this: 1) create a new empty file; 2) pipe the contents from the existing file into the new one until you encounter the line to be replaced; 3) write out the replacement line; 4) pipe the rest of the original file's data. 5) Rename the new file over the old one. ("Piping" means using something like `io.Copy` in Go. If you're reading/writing in a linewise manner, just use appropriate stuff from the `bufio` package).

Comment: Also, if the replacement line is of the same length as the original one, you can "patch" the file "in place". I hope the logic to implement it should be apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*line* implies a text file, and since those generally have varying line lengths, there is no way to replace a line in the file on disk unless the new one has the same length (the operating system does not provide a way to open or close gaps in a file).

Databases, on the other hand, generally operate on fixed-size entities (per table), so there, the database can replace the content of a 'record' with new data and also keep a list of previously used records that are now deleted and can be recycled when new data is inserted.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not follow the clarification you provided with the database part. Could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: @paiakshay998 if you're dealing with fixed-length records, like in a database, this is certainly possible as you can just calculate the offset of a record you need to update. The problem with a regular text file is that you don't know the offset of where a certain line will start.

Comment: Many databases support this functionality without fixed-length records, too, but they also end up writing entirely new records in such a case, akin to creating a new file on the disk (basically what the OP is already doing).